Why to use provider in state management while we can use Stateful builder widget?
So I was introduced to the idea of rebuilding a certain portion of a flutter application in order to display changes to the UI, and I understood that rebuilding the whole screen is expensive in terms of time, and heck, the app might rebuild the whole widget tree.
I've found that using a package called provider Provider package documentations
solves this problem easily, and I tried to bear with learning the new tech.
However, Flutter has announced a new widget called StatefulBuilder StatefulBuilder documentations, which does the same thing in theory, but I wonder if there is anything else to consider when choosing between the two?

In complicated apps, use Provider for scalable and effective global state management and StatefulBuilder for straightforward, localized state changes.

StatefulBuilder is a good solution when it needs to rebuild a small portion of the screen. For example, in a rider app like Uber, the driver can change his availability status by a switch button. Here the state of the switch button is independent of the rest of the screen so to achieve this we can wrap our switch button inside a stateful button.
But if we need to handle a complex state for a full screen or a list etc. then it is better to use a stateful widget or Provider for state management. The advantage of using a provider is that it allows us to separate the business logic into a separate class (acting like a view model).

Also i want to add to use consumer that is related to provider on the only part that is going to change to avoid building the whole widget tree again and lose the power of provider
